# Perl - splice() issues

Tags: perl, splice

I'm having trouble using the perl splice() method. Bellow you will see that I first identify the indexes of the two strings that I am looking for and then perform splice() using the indexes to get the desired array.

My code is as follows:

```
my @a = qw(foo bar bazz elements in between hello bazz johnny bl aba);
my $z = 0;

for (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++)
{
    next unless $a[$i] =~ /bazz/;

    if( $z eq 0 )
    {
        $z++;
        $first = $i;
    }
    else
    {
        $second = $i;
    }               
    my @b = splice(@a,$first,$second);
    print Dumper(@b);
}
```

And the result of the print is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = 'bazz';
$VAR2 = 'elements';
$VAR3 = 'in';
$VAR4 = 'between';
$VAR5 = 'hello';
$VAR6 = 'bazz';
$VAR7 = 'johnny';
```

I was under the impression that splice takes the chunk in between the given limits, inclusive of course. I don't understand why element 'johnny' would be there. Shouldn't the list stop at the second 'bazz' ?

Thank you for any pointers on this issue.

Comment: You should pass a reference to Dumper as such: `print Dumper \@b;`.

Comment: Doesn't Perl complain about `$second` being `undef` when you use it?  It would if you had `use strict; use warnings;` as you should.  Also, Perl uses mathematical comparator symbols (`==`, `>=`, ...) to compare numbers, and alphabetical comparator symbols (`eq`, `ge`, ...) to compare strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument is the *length* of the slice, not the index of the end of the slice.

Answer (score 2):

[`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) takes the arguments as

```
splice @ARRAY, $OFFSET, $LENGTH, @REPLACE_LIST;
```

It removes `$LENGTH` elements from the `@ARRAY` starting at index `$OFFSET` and replaces them by the given list (or deletes them from the array when the empty list is (implicitely) given).

It seems you want an *array slice* instead:

```
my @b = @a[$first .. $second];
print Dumper \@b;
```